# Trouble passing multiple database tables to JTables

Tags: java, mysql

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Main.java to edit this template
 */
package databaseschema;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


/**
 *
 * @author mrich
 */
public class DatabaseSchema2 {  
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException { 
        //Sets up gui
        JFrame frame =new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        
        

        frame.add(addPane());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    
    
    public static JTabbedPane addPane() throws SQLException{
        String user = loginButton.Instance.username;
        String pass= loginButton.Instance.password;
        String url= loginButton.Instance.server;
        String database= loginButton.Instance.database;
        JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        ArrayList dataList = getData(url,database,user,pass);
        for(int k = 0;k<dataList.size();k++){
        JTable table = new JTable();        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
       
        
        CachedRowSet data=(CachedRowSet) dataList.get(k);
        
        ResultSetMetaData mD = data.getMetaData();
            int columns = mD.getColumnCount();
            String[] colName = new String[columns];
                for(int j =0;j<columns;j++)
               
                {colName[j]=mD.getColumnName(j+1);
                model.setColumnIdentifiers(colName);
                }
        
            
           while(data.next()){
                ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 0;i<columns;i++){
                    
                    String row = data.getString(i+1);
                    rows.add(row); 
                }
                model.addRow(rows.toArray());
            }
            table.setModel(model);
            pane.addTab(mD.getTableName(k+1), scroll);}
            return pane;
        }
        
    
    public static ArrayList getData( String url, String database, String user, String pass){
        //Passes data for all accessible databases using sql statements populated with user entered data
        PreparedStatement stat,stat2;
        ResultSet data,dbName;
        String dbURLString ="jdbc:mysql://"+url+"/"+database;
        String dbSql="Show tables from "+database;
        String sqlState;
        
        ArrayList<ResultSet> dataList;
        dataList = new ArrayList<ResultSet>();

                
        try {
            
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURLString,user,pass)) { 
                stat = conn.prepareStatement(dbSql);
                dbName=stat.executeQuery();
               while(dbName.next()){
                RowSetFactory fact = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
                CachedRowSet crs = fact.createCachedRowSet();
                
               sqlState="Select * from "+dbName.getString("Tables_in_"+database)+";";
                stat2 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlState);
                data = stat2.executeQuery();
                crs.populate(data);
                dataList.add(crs);
                }
              
                conn.close();
                loginButton.Instance.dispose();
                return dataList;
            }

            
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseSchema2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get data", ex);
            loginButton.Instance.errLabel.setVisible(true);
        }
        
        return (null);
        
   }
   
    
}
```

So I have been working on this for a couple weeks now. I am new to Java coding with SQL. I have gotten this far and I am just lost. I need assistance getting everything sorted out. I am able to get a single table to show up or a jumbled mess of of all three tables. It will have all three ids at the top of the scroll pane. If you can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Edit your question and add your code as properly formatted text.

Comment: You also need to explain exactly what "trouble" you're having.

Comment: Sorry I had it filled out then I couldn't figure out how to indent the code correctly so I had to redo it.

Comment: Should `ResultSet data = (ResultSet) dataList.get(2);` be `get(k)`?

Comment: yes it should. I was just testing out what showed up when I tried 2.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my `CachedRowSet` and factory declaration inside my while loop and changed my `arraylist` from rowset to `cachedrowset`. This fixed my issues. Thanks and hopefully it helps someone else in the future.